# How can i generate random numbers between 5 and 40000 in C?

Tags: c

Im trying to generate random numbers between 5 and 40000 with using rand() function.And add them to 3x3 matris.
I have tried multiply rand with rand and mod 39996 is that correct solution you think ?

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
srand(time(0));

int **matris;

matris=(int **)calloc(3,sizeof(int));   // ilk pointerla 3 kutuya boldum yani 3 satir

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

    matris[i]=calloc(3,sizeof(int));   // buradada 3 kutunun herbirinin icini 3e boldum
}

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){             // i= matrisin satirini j= matrisin sutununu temsil ediyor
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        matris[i][j]= 5 + ((rand()*rand())%39996); // burada rand() fonksiyonunun karesini alip isleme devam ettim. 5 ile 40000 arasi sayilar olusturuyor.
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        printf("%d\t",matris[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: @cinoxil Why the `rand()*rand()`?

Comment: `sizeof (int)` may be different than `sizeof (int*)`: your first calloc is wrong. I prefer to use the dereferenced pointer itself as multiplier: `int **matris = calloc(3, sizeof *matris /* sizeof (int*) */ );`

Comment: @Ackdari because rand() fuction's max value is 32767. in here its work like for example first rand generate 3 second generate 5 3x5=10.

Comment: If available, use the `arc4random_uniform` function, e.g. `5 + arc4random_uniform(39996)`

Answer (score 2):

When `RAND_MAX` is large, the below is sufficient, although it has a   bias.

```
matris[i][j] = 5 + (rand() % 39996);
```

As `RAND_MAX` may only be 32767 (as apperntly in [OP's case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61454757/how-can-i-generate-random-numbers-between-5-and-40000-in-c/61455061#comment108711088_61454757)) , we need more random bits.

```
if (RAND_MAX == 32767) {
  long r = rand();
  r *= (RAND_MAX + 1L);
  r += rand();
  matris[i][j] = 5 + (r % 39996);
} else {
  matris[i][j] = 5 + (rand() % 39996);
}
```

---

`rand()*rand()` does not form a uniform distribution.  In this case we want `(RAND_MAX+1)*(RAND_MAX+1)` different values.

The range of random numbers generated needs to be at least [0...39996).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generating-random-number-range-c/

As C does not have an inbuilt function for generating a number in the range, but it does have rand function which generate a random number from 0 to RAND_MAX. With the help of `rand()` a number in range can be generated as `num = (rand() % (upper – lower + 1)) + lower`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about bias (*)

```
randomvalue = rand() % 39996 + 5;
```

*some values will have a higher probability of being *chosen* than others*

---

> `RAND_MAX` is 32767

Hmmm...

call `rand()` twice and use one single bit from one of the values

```
// return unbiased random between 5 and 40000
// assuming RAND_MAX == 32767
int unbiased(void) {
    int value;
    do {
        value = rand(); // 0 to 32767
        value = value * 2; // even value from 0 to 65534
        if (rand() & 0x800) value = value + 1; // 0 to 65535
    } while (value > 39995); // ignore biased results
    return value + 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int random(int min, int max) {
    return (rand() % (max - min + 1)) + min; 
}
```